# Is it possible to call xsl Apache FOP without providing an input file but instead passing a string

Tags: python, xml, xslt, subprocess, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a PDF using FOP. To do this I am taking in a template file, initialling its values with Jinja2 and then passing it through to fop with a system call.

Is it possible to do a subprocess call to FOP without passing through an input file but instead a string containing the XML directly? And if so how would I go about doing so?

I was hoping for something like this

```
fop -fo "XML here" -pdf output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes actually it was possible.

Using python I was able to import the xml from the file into lxml.etree:

```
tree = etree.parse('FOP_PARENT.fo.xml')
```

And then by using the etree to parse the include tags:

```
tree.xinclude()
```

Then it was a simple case of converting the xml back into unicode:

```
xml = etree.tounicode(tree)
```

This is how I got the templates to work. Hopefully this helps someone who has the same issue!